# How to import source code or project by the eclipse plugin of Dynamsoft SAW standalone?

Tags: eclipse, version-control

Recently I tried eclipse plugin of Dynamsoft SAW standalone for source control. But I found a problem that I cannot import project by this plugin as same as git or CVS does. Can anybody tell me how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Rachel from Dynamsoft. I'm afraid currently SourceAnywhere Eclipse plugin doesn't support importing project from source control server directly. I will forward your request to our R&D team for future consideration. Currently, you can perform Get from SourceAnywhere GUI client (Windows/Java/Mac) and then open the project in Eclipse. Thank you for using SourceAnywhere.